# PostgreSQL:error reusing the prepared statement in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, odbc, postgresql-9.3, psqlodbc

**Description**: i have a problem executing the prepared statement more than once with binding parameters. 1st time it executing correct then resetting the parameters,statement and when i try to execute same prepared statement next time it is failed giving the error like this.

**Details**: i am executing a prepared statement with binding some parameters ,after executing i am resting the prepared statement and unbinding the parameters. when try to execute the same prepared statement it is giving the error :"27:**Error fetching numeric attribute: ColAttribute for this type not implemented yet**".  i am using libodbc++ library. when i debug it is going wrong at this line(**libodbc++** code line)

Line :ResultSet* rs=ODBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW_DEBUG(**FILE**, **LINE**) ResultSet(this,hstmt_,hideMe);

Error: "**27:Error fetching numeric attribute: ColAttribute for this type not implemented yet**"

PostgreSQL version number you are running:

How you installed PostgreSQL:PostgreSQL 9.3.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit

Changes made to the settings in the postgresql.conf file: No

Operating system and version:windows 8.1 (64-bit)

What program you're using to connect to PostgreSQL:ODBC 3.5 (libodbc++) library

Is there anything relevant or unusual in the PostgreSQL server logs?:No

For questions about any kind of error:

What you were doing when the error happened / how to cause the error:"27:Error fetching numeric attribute: ColAttribute for this type not implemented yet"

Thanks & Regards
Balakrishna

Comment: Can you provide us with the prepared statement?

Comment: some one says that it is due to  SQLColAttribute function is called with a field identifier that the driver doesn't recognize.

is it true ?? if it is then what are field identifier supported by postgresql driver ??

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how the libodbc++ handles the parameters and the queries. There are two ways to fix this :

```
 1. Upgrade the libodbc++ to use 7.4(V3) protocol.
 2. If you are using old libodbc++, then change disable the UseServerSidePrepare parameter in odbc configuration files.
```

**Explaination** for UseServerSidePrepare = 0 in odbc configuration :

> The psqlodbc controls more than just whether to use unnamed or named
>   plans in the server. With UseServerSidePrepare=0, parameters are
>   handled completely in the driver, replacing the parameter markers with
>   the values in the query itself.

Note : There may well be applications where UseServerSidePrepare=1 
gives a performance hit, especially when running against < 9.2 servers. 
It's still a better default IMHO, you can still turn it off if you have to.

**PS**: I know the question was asked years back, but i recently faced the same issue and had to very less resource which actually worked.